# JQuery + (Synchronous)jax + XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

**Summary**: I'm currently having a problem with JQuery + Ajax, where the XMLHTTPRequest is undefined (at least that's what it seems to be) in the Error function.

- **JQuery Version**: 1.9.1
- **Server**: Websphere 7.0
- **Browser we got the problem on: Internet Explorer *(Couldn't reproduce the problem myself, since it happened to a client)***

**Problem Description**: After we receive in our Server the Request, we process it doing what we need in the Server Side without any problems and send the Response (200) back to the Client, but for some reason, we found out that in very rare opportunities, Ajax ends up in the Error Function.

---

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    async:false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "randomURL",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    beforeSend:someRandomFunction,
    success:someOtherRandomFunction,
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var responseText = XMLHttpRequest.responseText;
        var contentType = XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
        alert("Response Text: " + responseText + "\n Content Type: " + contentType + "\n Text Status: " + textStatus + "\n Error Thrown: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

---

Giving us an alert like this

```
Response Text: undefined
Content Type: null
Text Status: error
Error Thrown: [object Error]
```

We don't know why this is happening. We suspect it's related to the Browser and some kind of configuration it could have but that's all we could figure out. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't reproduce this at all?

Comment: I tried but sadly, I couldn't reproduce it at all. In my own Application Instance, everything works as it should.

Comment: Wild speculation: Some browser doesn't like you masking the global `XMLHttpRequest` variable with a local version. Call your local variable `xhr` instead.

Comment: If you structured your alert a little bit better to give you the actual error thrown + stack it may be more useful for debugging.